# формат Json и MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Всем привет.
На главной странице есть скрипт, который прогружает файл do_rating.php, который создает/пересоздает и заполняет json файл данными от запроса.

**(Файл всегда пустой, но данные есть, делал запрос в workbench MySqL)**

```
Скрипт

<script>
    $("#myForm").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post('do_rating.php');

        $.getJSON('../json/goods_rating.json', function(data) {
                // Очищение таблицы
                $('#resultRating').empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $('#resultRating').append('<tr><td>' +
                        data[i].category + '</td><td>' +
                        data[i].numbers + '</td></tr>');
                }
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

А вот и содержание do_rating.php...

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)
or die ("Не могу создать соединение");

$query = "select
                categories.name as category,
                count(goods.id) as numbers
          from
                categories left join goods on categories.id = goods.id_category
          group by
                categories.name
          order by
                numbers desc;";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query)
or die("Не могу выполнить запрос");

if($result) {
    $json_result = [];  // массив для данных, полученных из запроса
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); // количество полученных строк

    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; ++$i) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        array_push($json_result, ['category'=>$row[0], 'numbers'=>$row[1]]);
    } // for

    // кодировать массив в формат JSON
    $json_res = json_encode($json_result);
    file_put_contents('../json/goods_rating.json', $json_res);

    // очищаем результат
    mysqli_free_result($result);
} // if

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

У других людей код работает, у меня же - нет.
Все же логично, данные с запроса json_encod-ю в строку формата json, сохраняю в файл, а на главной странице идет считывание этого файла через getJSON в строки таблицы...но пустота...Помогите пожалуйста.

**Добавил**
Jquery подключен, но phpstorm не видит метод $.post, все остальное прекрасно понимает, может, в интерпретаторе дело?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если раз конкретно проблема: не записываются данные в goods_rating.json? Или не вычитываются из него?

Comment: И еще - $.post асинхронная, т.е. прежде, чем читать что-то из goods_rating.json, нужно дождаться, пока do_rating.php туда что-то запишет.

Comment: Не записываются данные в json файл!

Comment: Тогда проверяйте do_rating.php: подключается ли к базе, возвращаются ли какие-то данные, есть файл по указанному пути, есть ли для него права на запись...

Comment: проблему решил, переходите сюда.
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616305/%D0%A1%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-json-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0