# Считывание с JSON файла

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Есть метод GetSelect - я получу список категорий из моей бд "id, name".

```
function GetSelect($link) {
        $query = "select categories.id, categories.name from categories";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query)
        or die("Не могу выполнить запрос");

        if($result) {
            $json_result = [];
            $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; ++$i) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
                array_push($json_result, ['id'=>$row[0], 'name'=>$row[1]]);
            } // for
            $json_res = json_encode($json_result);
            file_put_contents('../json/categories.json', $json_res);
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        } // if
    }
```

Все прекрасно, данные JSON **успешно** сохраняются.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но теперь я не могу их вывести в select список "value - key". Скрипт написал - толку ноль. ***Список пуст. Что делать?(***

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('../json/categories.json', function(data) {
            // Очищение списка
            $('#mySelect').empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $('#mySelect').append('<option value="'
                    + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>');
            }
        }
    );
</script>
```

Добавил: ФАЙЛ ПРОШЕЛ ВАЛИДАЦИЮ!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может быть из-за того что вы отправляете list?
В плане вы отправили `[{}]`, а не `{}`

Comment: Допустим это проблема, как её избежать?

Comment: users прав. У Вас не валидный JSON. "Оберните" весь вывод в фигурные скобки и все заработает. $json_res = json_encode($json_result); замените на $json_res = "{"+json_encode($json_result)+"}";

Comment: Не могу, жалуется на запятые тогда в json файле(перечисление данных)

Comment: Все работает как надо, я поместил файл в ту же директорию что и HTML файл. (http://pastebin.com/DDeJpekV)

Comment: Сделал  $json_res = "{"+json_encode($json_result)+"}";, теперь содержимое json файла просто 0. одна цифра.

Comment: да какая нафиг разница где json файл лежит, если я знаю к нему путь.

Comment: что за бред про невалидный json, если он сформирован через `json_encode()` ?

Comment: файл прошел валидацию, картинку прикрепил.

Comment: @Alakay дак и проверьте в инструментах браузера что в ответ на xhr запрос приходит? нефиг относительные пути писать в url.

Comment: по сабжу, используйте нормальный URL для запроса, наверняка приходит 404 и функция построения списка просто не вызывается даже

Comment: Да мне сейчас не важно как url выглядит, запрос и все остальное - верно. Не выводит только.

Comment: Да мне сейчас не важно как url выглядит, запрос и все остальное - верно. Не выводит только.

Comment: @Alakay отладчик JS в браузере включите и вперед тогда.

Comment: Выдало ошибку, что json файлы не найдены.
jquery.js:4 GET http://localhost:63342/json/categories.json 404 (Not Found)

Comment: НО ПРИ ЭТОМ ФАЙЛ В ДИРЕКТОРИИ JSON/CATEGORIES.JSON СУЩЕСТВУЕТ!

Comment: Делайте отладку и проверьте что в data после получения из файла. Вероятно у вас там ничего не читается.

Comment: Фишка в том, что у меня путь к index.php идет через "/JSON_KDA/index.php". Где JSON_KDA - название проекта.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Проблему решил путем сноса phpstorm.

Comment: уже пошутить нельзя.

Comment: Для справки: тут сайт не анекдотов (шутят максимум в комментариях), а предметных ответов, полезных **широкому кругу** читателей.